# How can I configure keycloak to route to /auth? --http-relative-path is not working

Tags: kubernetes, keycloak, traefik

I am trying to modify a kubernetes keycloak deployment to respond on `/auth` in place of `/`. I see in the documentation that this should be possible by setting `--http-relative-path` to `/auth`. I have attempted this and it causes all the services to receive `Connection refused` from the keycloak service. Is this possibly an issue with keycloak or could there be another config required?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was that the networking solution was not routing to the service because the health checks had not been updated with the correct routes.

```
        readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /health/ready
            port: 8080
          initialDelaySeconds: 30
          periodSeconds: 10
          timeoutSeconds: 1
          failureThreshold: 20
        startupProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /health/ready
            port: 8080
          initialDelaySeconds: 30
          periodSeconds: 10
          timeoutSeconds: 1
          failureThreshold: 20
        livenessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /health/ready
            port: 8080
          initialDelaySeconds: 30
          periodSeconds: 10
          timeoutSeconds: 1
          failureThreshold: 20
```

Changing these to `/auth/health/ready` fixed the ready checks.